# Powershell smo different assembly Versions

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, .net-assembly, smo

I have run into a number of strange errors when running my smo scripts. And I think I pinned it down to Powershell loading different Assembly files.
I updated from SQL Server 2008 to 2012. This bug only happens for an updated Server, it works fine for a freshly installed 2008 and 2012 server.
I then open a powershell console with 'sqlps' or via Microsoft Management Studio and run my script. I then run into different kind of errors all over my script.
When examining the behaviour I found out that whenever I create an Object via the `New-Object` command it is loaded from this assembly

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

But when I use `get-Item` on the sql Provider PS-PATH it is pulled from from this

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
>   assembly.

I assume this to be the cause of all those different errors I stumble upon.

Is there a way to tell powershell which assembly is used? Do I need to update the PS Provider to use the 12.0.0.0 edition? Is this a configuration issue or can I fix it within the script?

Update

I have tried to manually add Assemblies with

> Add-Type -path "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll"

and also

> Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"

I tried to force the use of version 11.0.0.0, which did not work for me. Seems like you cannot reload an assembly once it has been added.